# Why don't cells double gene expression after S-Phase?

Tags: genetics, cell-biology, gene-expression, cell-cycle

In the cell cycle (G1-S-G2-M), all of the DNA is replicated during the S or Synthesis stage. The cell may then spend some considerable time in the G2 phase before splitting in the M phase. Since there is double the amount of genetic material in the G2 phase, what mechanism if any, prevents the amount of gene expression from also doubling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the double strand is duplicated, the *old strand* (or, in other terms, the template) is methylated : this modification is enough to prevent the bind by the RNApol system and, by so, the transcription. 
By methylation, DNA-repair systems are able to detect which is the newer strand, to discover and fix replication errors.

[Here](https://www.annualreviews.org/doi/10.1146/annurev.bi.52.070183.000521) you can find additional infos